# AFRAME: Android metallnesMap and roughnessMap issue

Tags: three.js, aframe

Tried to use in my project a model with metallnesMap and roughnessMap. On iOS everything looks good, but on Android it seems to be avoiding these maps. What could be the cause and if there any solution?

On iOS:

[image]

On Android:

[image]

Use A-FRAME 1.1.0, .glb model exported from Blender

Before the model looked dark on each devices but adding to the scene 'renderer="colorManagement: true"' and adding envMap has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not in the code and in the model material, just needed a help from skilled 3D-modeller.