# Output encoding in Aframe

Tags: three.js, aframe

This question is related to [AFRAME: Android metallnesMap and roughnessMap issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812649/aframe-android-metallnesmap-and-roughnessmap-issue)

Main idea: I want to see the same metal texture on iOS and Android devices in my aframe project. In the [viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) it is realy the same, but there only three.js

Can I change somehow WebGLRenderer.outputEncoding in Aframe?
The propertie is undefined for a scene - this.el.sceneEl.renderer.outputEncoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add renderer="colorManagement: true" scene attribute to set renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;